# Удаление экземпляра обьекта

Tags: ооп, c++

Не могу понять, почему падает программа при вызове функции:

```
template <class T>void set<T>::del(elem<T> *x){
    if(count==1){
        head=tail=NULL;
        count=0;
    }else{
        if(x==head){
            head=head->next;
        }else{
            elem<T> *tmp=head;
            if(x==tail){
                while(!(tmp->next==tail)){
                    tmp=tmp->next;
                }
                tail=tmp;
            }else{
                while(!(tmp->next==x)){
                    tmp=tmp->next;
                }
                tmp->next=x->next;
            }
        }
    }
    //delete x->data;
    delete x;
}
```

В месте комментирования, при раскомментирваннии падает. Если писать с разименовании - падает. Но по при этом выдается же значение объекта, а не ссылка, или я что-то путаю?

```
template <class T> struct elem{                      //Элемент списка
    T* data;
    elem* next;
};

template <class T> struct set{
public:
    set():count(0),head(NULL),tail(NULL){};
    set(set<T> &s);                        
    set(int c, T &m);                      
//  ~set();                                          //Деструктор

    void test(T* x);

private:
    elem<T> *head;                                   //Голова
    elem<T> *tail;                                   //Хвост
    int count;                                       //Количество элементов

    void del(elem<T> *x);                            //Удаление по адрессу элемента
};

template <class T>elem<T> * set<T>::addh(T *x){      //Добавление в голову (протестировано)
elem<T> *temp = new elem<T>;                     //Указатель на временный элемент
temp->data=x;                                    //Записываем указатель во временный элемент
temp->next=head;                                 //Записываем следующим элементом голову
count++;
return temp;                                     //Возвращаем указатель на новый элемент
}
```

Comment: Можете весь код где-нибудь разместить? Из этого куска не очень понятно, что происходит.

Comment: Все зависит от того, как именно выделяется память под elem::data. В приведенном коде этого не видно.

Comment: Не Вы создали temp->data - не Вам его удалять.

Comment: А оно нужно удалять его или он сам удалится?

Comment: Зависит от того, как был создан `х`, который передан в функцию `addh()`.

Comment: Можно подробнее об этом моменте?

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что если этого не сделать то получится утечка памяти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите.

```
void blablabla()
{
  ....
  my_class xi;
  set<my_class> list;
  list.addh(&xi); // все хорошо - добавить элемент мы можем
  // теперь если мы элемент грохнем, то выполнится инструкция
  // delete x->data; т.е. по сути delete xi; а xi аллоцирован на стеке
  // итого - программе снесет крышу.
}
```

Получается, самое надежное - при добавлении элемента в контейнер добавлять не его самого, а конструировать новый объект, который будет копией добавляемого, и уже именно его добавлять в контейнер.

Т.е. ф-цию нужно переписать как:

```
template <class T>elem<T> * set<T>::addh(T *x)
{
  elem<T> *temp = new elem<T>;
  T *xi = new T(x); // вот оно!
  temp->data=xi;
  temp->next=head;
  count++;
  return temp;
}
```